# Trying to add duplicates of the same layout (android)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to duplicate the same layout which contains several views and I want the ability to be able to change the fields when the new views are added dynamically. Is this possible? If so what view would I use and how would I go about doing it?

Comment: Please add some more detail.  Yes, you may use the same layout in different activities, and then do some customizing from the Java code for that activity.

Comment: grammatically means ?

Comment: question is vague, please refer the guides on https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a question.

Comment: @VivekMishra sorry just edited it to dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a template layout through a factory of views. So, say you've the relative layout *my_template_view.xml* where you have 1 `TextView` with id *_my_template_text_*, you could add 3 of those programmatically like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    RelativeLayout newView = ViewFactory.getNewTemplateView();
    TextView myText = newView.findViewById(R.id.my_template_text);
    myText.setText("Set at " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    parent.add(newView)
}
```

whereas the trick is to find the text view through the outer layout *newView.findViewById()* because otherwise they all will point to the same views instances. Also, the view factory new method should instantiate a new `RelativeLayout` every time.
But, depending on your app, for these types of problems usually [an Adapter](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) which binds views to the dataset on the fly is a way better solution.

Comment: So if I had 2 text views and a image view  that were aligned horizontally, this would work?

Comment: @Anthony I'm not so sure what you exactly mean with "this would work?" ... try it out, that's the best way to know. Start with the simplest case, say 1 view ... if that works, add the 2nd view ... if that works, add the 3rd view, and there you are! Start with the simplest implementation, change it and improve it at need. Debug to see at any point what you have. Have a nice coding!

Comment: I can't call .getNewTemplateView()

Comment: @Anthony the ViewFactory in my code is your factory, so you implement such method _getNewTemplateView()_.